# My job has changed and my performance has suffered in a key area, what should I do?

Tags: performance-reviews, culture, company

I recently had a mediocre performance review. My job has changed as the company has become more "call center" like. I have high ratings with client organizations I serve, co-workers as mentor and trainer for both clients and staff. When a new team member joined last year, I did spend time mentoring him to learn the job which he did well. I did my work for client companies but my "call center" numbers were slightly below average such as times available on a new Queue system, restroom breaks--which was never an issue before, and I even came up with a plan to share the workload efficiently, mentor and train new staff and connect with clients--which was turned around in my review as a highlight to my own deficiencies. I am so close to leaving. I have a great deal of education, even more than many of my supervisors, but I am uncertain what to do. My low ratings pretty much guarantee I would not be considered for a promotion as the "numbers" aren't right. FYI, my typing skills are decent but I am not lightening on the keyboard with a random queue call. Thoughts?

Comment: Questions asking specifically "what should I do" or left open ended ("Thoughts?") don't fit the Q&A model on The Workplace very well. You will likely get better results if you rephrase your question to mention your specific goals, what you're trying to achieve, what your options are, and other details.

Comment: How to I adapt to a call center world which is purely about numbers for the day?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Speak to management in hopes of making changes.    Maybe you will positively effect change by expressing your concerns.
2. Accept the new system, and change your work habits to succeed in the new system.
3. Leave.

This wouldn't be the first time a company simply changed how they did business, and the employees beholden to the old system simply got left in the dust.  I've been that employee myself -- hired to program in Microsoft technologies, then had the company decide to switch to Java a few months later.   Ultimately, I left when I could not resist the change any further.

Make a choice.   Do you like the company enough to stay and try to change it, or accept it?   Or go find a new job.

Comment: I enjoy training and mentoring new staff and planning programs for the organization. My company is about the phones, the numbers and your typing skills. I may leave.

Comment: @Westerling, it sounds like what you want to do and what your company values are not in alignment. What is keeping you from leaving?

Comment: The pay is good and so are the benefits, but man ( and woman) does not live by bread alone, so I hear. I have  been looking around, more exploratory at this point. One senior leader was saying how in a few years an AI will be able to do many of the mundane things. What I hear is we can do more with fewer people.